# What's the best approach for building this grid?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem and i will be grateful if anyone helps me. I have been struggling with this grid for 2 days. I have to build a grid/table like this. What's the best approach?
I tried using a table using bootstrap without success.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate the height of upper-left row and set same top margin to the corresponding div in it's css.

```js
//get height of div id "r1"
    var r1height = document.getElementById('r1').clientHeight;
    //get height of div id "r2"
    var r2height = document.getElementById('r2').clientHeight;
    //get height of div id "r3"
    var r3height = document.getElementById('r3').clientHeight;

//set margin top in r2's css which is equal to r1's height
    document.getElementById("r2").style.marginTop = r1height+"px";
    //set margin top in r3's css which is equal to (r1+r2)'s height
    document.getElementById("r3").style.marginTop = r1height+r2height+"px";
    //set margin top in r4's css which is equal to (r1+r2+r3)'s height
    document.getElementById("r4").style.marginTop = r1height+r2height+r3height+"px";
```

```css
.fortable{
  overflow-x: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: block;
}
.left{
      
      border:solid thin black;
      width:49%;
      display:inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">TEXT</div>
        <div class="col">TEXT</div>
        <div class="col">TEXT</div>
        <div class="col">TEXT</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col fortable" id="r1">
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col fortable" id="r2">
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col fortable" id="r3">
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col fortable" id="r4">
           <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
          <div class="left">TEXT</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I really like your solution, but what if I don't only have two items but n items? It's not a problem have the horizontal scroll. For "n items" I mean the items with the border

Comment: I have updated the snippet. I hope it's what you were asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to look at the design linearly (I mean row )
Please look at these few lines of code

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
      Column
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using CSS grid-area would be a very simple option.

```css
div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas: 
    'text1 . . .'
    '. text2 . .'
    '. . text3 .'
    '. . . text4';
}

.text1 {
    grid-area: text1;
}

.text2 {
    grid-area: text2;
}

.text3 {
    grid-area: text3;
}

.text4 {
    grid-area: text4;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <p class="text1">Text 1</p>
    <p class="text2">Text 2</p>
    <p class="text3">Text 3</p>
    <p class="text4">Text 4</p>
</div>
```

The dots represent empty space. They also don't have to be broken onto different lines. It is just easier to read. You can use grid-template-columns along with it to change how much space each of the items takes up.

Comment: It was an interesting idea, but it certainly was not the solution for this UI.